# How can I get Merlin to warn me when I've incorrectly implemented a module interface defined in a .mli file?

Tags: ocaml, merlin

I have two files:

foo.ml

```ml
let foo = ()
```

foo.mli

```ml
val foo: int -> int
```

How can I get Merlin to warn me that I've incorrectly implemented the interface?

Comment: I don't think that's Merlin's role. I think you should look at Dune or other build mechanisms for OCaml.

Comment: I was wrong! You can query Merlin(in Vim) with :MerlinErrorCheck and it will generate an error message if the signatures don't match.